# Player Movements in RPG Java Game - Simultaneous key pressing

Tags: java, if-statement, keyboard, logic

In my java RPG game, a KeyHandler checks which of the WASD key is pressed during playstate:

```
`if (gp.gameState == gp.playState) {
     if (code == KeyEvent.VK_W){
         upPressed = true;
     }
     if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A){
         leftPressed = true;
     }
     if (code == KeyEvent.VK_S){
         downPressed = true;
     }
     if (code == KeyEvent.VK_D){
         rightPressed = true;
     }`
```

Inside the update fuction, a the value of a string variable called "direction" changes based on which key the KeyHandler recognized:

```
`if(keyH.upPressed || keyH.downPressed || keyH.leftPressed || keyH.rightPressed ){
     if (keyH.upPressed){
         direction = "up";
     }
     if(keyH.downPressed){
         direction = "down";
     }
     if(keyH.leftPressed){
         direction = "left";
     }
     if(keyH.rightPressed){
         direction = "right";
     }`
```

After checking for eventual collisions, the player moves based on his direction in the same update fuction:

```
`if (!collisionOn) {
      if(Objects.equals(direction, "up")) {
          worldY -= speed;
      }
      if(Objects.equals(direction, "down")) {
          worldY += speed;
      }
      if(Objects.equals(direction, "left")) {
          worldX -= speed;
      }
      if(Objects.equals(direction, "right")) {
          worldX += speed;
      }`
```

My problem is that when pressing some of the keys simoultaneously the resulting action is not what is expected: while holding the W key, if any other key between A,S or D changes the direction; while holding the S key, only pressing A or D changes the direction, W is not working. While holding A only pressing D changes the direction, W and S not working. While holding D, no other directional key works. This behavior seems to be linked to the order of the if statements in my second snippets of code, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: *this behavior seems to be linked to the order of the if statements* - well, did you change the order of the statements to validate your thought?  A KeyEvent is only generated for the last key pressed, so order should not matter, assuming your logic is correct. However, you should NOT be using a KeyListener. Instead you should be using `Key Bindings`. Check out: [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information.

Comment: On "pressed", add the direction to a `Set`, on "release" remove it - also, use the Key Bindings API instead

Answer (score 0):

Reading your description of the issue, it's clear that it is in fact linked to the order of the if statements. Whichever is the last statement to evaluate to `true` will determine the direction, ignoring any other keys that were pressed. I would suggest implementing it in a way that accounts for other key presses, such as:

```
if (!collisionOn) {
    if(keyH.upPressed) {
        worldY -= speed;
    }
    if(keyH.downPressed) {
        worldY += speed;
    }
    if(keyH.leftPressed) {
        worldX -= speed;
    }
    if(keyH.rightPressed) {
        worldX += speed;
    }
}
```

Without seeing more of the code, I'm not sure if your implementation allows this, but it shouldn't be difficult to obtain something to that effect.